# how to change link url on the web browser's status bar

Tags: javascript, dom

I already read many article about this issue in here, SO.

I just want to discuss how to do it.  NOT the moral issue.

--

for example.

at the google search webpage.

before I click the link,  the link does not indicate the google url.

but After I click the link with shift-key,  the url on the status bar is changed.

this mean the google webpage indicate 'Fake URL'.

the google compressed script is too difficult to read and analyze.

### #

edited

The second url should work on ie8 even if I click with ctrl key.

Comment: and sorry about my poor English!

Comment: Happily, this is such an annoyance that most browsers make it impossible these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser always shows link's href-attribute (no way to fake this), but you can capture the click event for link and do whatever you want. An example using jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this)
        .attr('orig_href', $(this).attr('href'))
        .attr('href', 'http://google.com');
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('orig_href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://this-url-will-be-shown/" onclick="location.href='http://this-url-will-be-opened/'; return false;">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use javascript to change the status in the window:

```
window.status='Your Message Here';
```

You would attach this to some event (onmouseover)

For example:

```
<A HREF="http://www.stackoverflow.com" onMouseOver="window.status='http://www.google.com'; return true"></A>
```